# Android Room with RXJava2; onNext() of emitter is not properly triggered

Tags: rx-java2, android-room, android-databinding

I am switching from async tasks to rxjava2 and have some issues with my code tests.

I have a room table of elements that have a certain monetary amount. On a usercontrol that is called DisplayCurrentBudget, a sum of all amounts should be displayed. This number must refresh everytime a new element is inserted. I tackled the requirement in two ways, but both produce the same result: My code does not care if the database is updated, it only updates when the fragment is recreated (onCreateView).

My first attempt was this:

```
//RxJava2 Test
    Observable<ItemS> ItemObservable = Observable.create( emitter -> {
        try {
            List<ItemS> movies = oStandardModel.getItemsVanilla();
            for (ItemS movie : movies) {
                emitter.onNext(movie);
            }
            emitter.onComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    });


    DisposableObserver<ItemS> disposable = ItemObservable.
        subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
        subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ItemS>() {
            public List<ItemS> BadFeelingAboutThis = new ArrayList<ItemS>();

            @Override
            public void onNext(ItemS movie) {
                // Access your Movie object here
                BadFeelingAboutThis.add(movie);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // Show the user that an error has occurred
            }
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                // Show the user that the operation is complete
                oBinding.DisplayCurrentBudget.setText(Manager.GetBigSum(BadFeelingAboutThis).toString());
            }
    });
```

I already was uncomfortable with that code. My second attempt produces the exact same result:

```
Observable<BigDecimal> ItemObservable2 = Observable.create( emitter -> {
        try {
            BigDecimal mySum = oStandardModel.getWholeBudget();
            emitter.onNext(mySum);
            emitter.onComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    });

    DisposableObserver<BigDecimal> disposable = ItemObservable2.
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(BigDecimal sum) {
                    // Access your Movie object here
                    oBinding.DisplayCurrentBudget.setText(sum.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // Show the user that an error has occurred
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // Show the user that the operation is complete
                }
            });
```

Any obvious issues with my code?

Thanks for reading, much appreciate it!

Edit:
I was asked what Manager.GetBigSum does, it actually does not do much. It only adds BigDecimal-Values of an Item list.

```
public static BigDecimal GetBigSum(List<ItemS> ListP){

    List<BigDecimal> bigDList = ListP.stream().map(ItemS::get_dAmount).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return bigDList.stream()
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Further, I simplified the query. But it still does not care about DB updates, only about fragment recreation:

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> oStandardModel.getItemsVanilla())
            .map(Manager::GetBigSum)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    e -> oBinding.DisplayCurrentBudget.setText(e.toString())
            );
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Array indices are zero based so `entry[0] to entry[length-1]` has all the entries of the array. How is `GetBigSum` implemented?

Comment: I put GetBigSum in my question, thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that would indicate the last item is dropped. You may have the wrong datasource query or `getItemsVanilla()` does not contain the data you think it should.

Answer (score 1):

Your rx logic has no error. That should be internal error in your `getWholeBudget`.

But why you write rx so complex?

For your case, you can just write:

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> oStandardModel.getItemsVanilla())
      .map(Manager::GetBigSum)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(
         e -> oBinding.DisplayCurrentBudget.setText(sum.toString()),
         e -> log.error(e));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i could greatly simplify the code (i put the current state in my question). I found out though what the actual problem is - the query executes when the form is recreated, not when the database changes. I thought the point of observables is to react on db changes?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
oStandardModel.getItemJointCatLive().observe(this, new Observer<List<ItemJointCat>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<ItemJointCat> oItemSP) {
                Single.fromCallable(() -> oStandardModel.getWholeBudget())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        e -> oBinding.DisplayCurrentBudget.setText(e.toString())
                );
            }
        });
```

My mistake was that I assumed RXjava2 does not need an onchanged event...now i just use onchanged event of livedata observer to trigger a simple rxjava2 query.

Do you think there is anything wrong with that approach?